# Failed to archive an app using xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I am trying to archive an app using `xcodebuild` but it keeps on failing at the last step of certificate signing with no clear error message. All I am getting is

```
Validate /Users/ashraftawfeeq/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<ProjectName>-ghodnwbxujykykezmtkiilwfkxrf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/<APP>/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/<APP>.app (in target '<Target>' from project '<ProjectName>')
    cd /Users/ashraftawfeeq/<ProjectRepo>
    builtin-validationUtility /Users/ashraftawfeeq/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<ProjectName>-ghodnwbxujykykezmtkiilwfkxrf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/<APP>/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/<APP>.app

Touch /Users/ashraftawfeeq/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<ProjectName>-ghodnwbxujykykezmtkiilwfkxrf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/<APP>/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/<APP>.app (in target <TargetName> from project <ProjectName>)
    cd /Users/ashraftawfeeq/<ProjectRepo>
    /usr/bin/touch -c /Users/ashraftawfeeq/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<ProjectName>-ghodnwbxujykykezmtkiilwfkxrf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/<APP>/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/<APP>.app

** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

When I try to archive using Xcode, it works as intended. Also when I try `xcodebuild build` it succeeds as well. Digging in the logs it seems like xcodebuild is not creating InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Application.

Comment: Show archive command.

Comment: xcodebuild archive -workspace Project.xcworkspace -scheme App\ Name -sdk iphoneos -configuration Beta

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching and debugging, it turned out that I have a Perl script that wasn't producing errors but without a non zero exit. The process continues and the archive is created but the process was failing.

Answer (score 0):

I removed 'arm64' from 'Excluded Architectures' (Target -> Build Settings).